# Strange default value for ints

Tags: objective-c, xcode, int, nslog

I am having a strange issue with initializing two int variables.

Here is my code:

```
int allHours;
int allMinutes;

NSLog(@"%d,%d",allHours,allMinutes);
```

And my output is:  `1,-1608887932`

What are these strange values? Is not 0 the default value for ints?

Thanks!

Comment: no, C, which Objective-C is a super set of, doesn't initialize non `static` variables for you.

Comment: @Jack True in this case, but not in general. Non-static variables that are an object reference other than unsafe unretained, are initialized. (Estimation: >80%)